# Perl Fill Out Form Based on Element ID

Tags: javascript, perl, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I am trying to use `WWW::Mechanize` to fill out a form. Unfortunately my page requires JS so I am now using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`.

Here is the element I am trying to fill out.

```
<input id="ember745" class="ssTextboxField"></input>
```

The [set_field()](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech->set_fields(_$name_=>_$value,_..._)) function takes an element name. How would I give it an element ID (ember 745) and have it fill the form in?

Here is my code so far

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(autoclose => 0);
$mech->get(URL);

$mech->form_number(1);
$mech->submit_form(
fields => {
    ember745 => $value
});
```

Comment: I can't test right now, but you can use simple CSS selectors with the [`field`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-field-selector-value-pre_events-post_events) method, e.g. `$mech->field('#ember745', $value);` I don't think you can do this with `set_fields`, which is called by `submit_form`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, had to use a selector

```
my $field = $mech->selector('input.ssTextboxField', single => 1);
$mech->field( $field => $value );
```